# Design on how to store large objects in a list

Tags: java, list, out-of-memory

I need a hint on an Interview question that I came across. I tried to find a solution but I need advice from experts over here. What are the different strategies you would employ had you came across this particular situation? The question and my thoughts are as follows:

Q. You want to store a huge number of objects in a list in java. The number of objects is very huge and gradually increasing, but you have very limited memory available. How would you do that?

> A. I answered by saying that, once the number of elements in the list
>   get over a certain threshold, I would dump them to a file. I would typically then build cache-like data-structure that would hold the most-frequently or recently added elements. I gave an analogy of page swapping employed by the OS.

Q. But this would involve disk access and it would be slower and affect the execution.

I did not know the solution for this and could not think properly during the interview. I tried to answer as:

> A. In this case, I would think of horizontally scaling the system or
>   adding more RAM.

Immediately after I answered this, my telephonic interview ended. I felt that the interviewer was not happy with the answer. But then, what should have been the answer.

Moreover, I am not curious only about the answer, I would like to learn about different ways with which this can be handled.

Comment: I think an answer would have been to use a stack or something where you can have a max size. Then set that max size according to the amount of memory your data type would take up and size of memory on device.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a discussion forum***.  Figuring out why an interviewer wanted a particular answer is off-topic here as it is too broad and opinion based.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: This is typically handled by arraylist in java right? With the load factor of 0.75 it will internally handle dynamic increase of elements. What will happen in case of very limited ram which can't hold all the elements in the list.

Comment: before this gets closed, this question mostly belongs to stackexchange. There must be similar questions. Hopefully they may give some idea.
Following too.

Comment: @JimGarrison as I said in the question, I am not curious about what Interviewer thought and etc. I want to know about different strategies and general design ideas that people may have here. If needed, I can remove the interview part and re-post it as my own question. Will that work?

Comment: @Shreyas How to port the question to skackexchange?

Comment: As of now, it is being upvoted. So *chalu de*. I found this - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ There may be similar questions over here, as answers to such questions are opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am not sure but It indicates that somewhat [Flyweight Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/flyweight_pattern.htm). This is the same pattern which is been used in String pool and its efficient implementation is must Apart from that, we need focus on database related tasks in order to persist the data if the threshold limit is surpassed. Another technique is to serialize it but as you said, the interviewer was not satisfied and wanted some other explanation.

Comment: Please include an explanation of the linked pattern (preferably with an example) so that the answer can remain selft-contained (i.e., so that it does not depend on external resources).

Comment: Also it's worth to mention that in order to use the flyweight pattern the objects have to be immutable.

Comment: Yes! Exactly.....that is what I was going to ask. It would make much sense to make the objects that need to be stored as immutable and store only references in the list.